# Calculate the magnitude of the vector field $\vec F= ({-GM/r^3})\vec r$

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, vector-fields

Apparently, if   $\vec F= ({-GM/r^3})\vec r$  then $||\vec F || = GM/r^2$

Why is that? The magnitude of a vector (and thus a vector field, I think) is the root of the sum of the squares of the components of the vector. But the definition of this vector field gave some general vector $\vec r$, so I'm not too sure how to apply that root of sum of squares formula here.

I can see that $GM/r^2$ is the antiderivative of $-GM/r^3$, but again there's the $\vec r$ to consider so I don't even know if that's relevant here.

Any help is appreciated, I'm rather confused.

Just for reference, here is the exact question from my text: [image]

I also don't understand why the textbook says that differentiating the rate of change of f towards the origin gives you the rate of change of f away from the origin. Maybe I'm misinterpreting what they're saying?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left|\vec F\right|=\left| {\frac{-GM}{r^3}}\vec r\right|=GM\frac{|\vec r|}{r^3}=GM\frac{r}{r^3}$$

Comment: Oh, jeez, thank you. One more stupid question though: why is $|\vec r| = r$? And what is the value of $r$ ($r$ wasn't at any point mentioned)? Is there some common notation or common interpretation of $\vec r$ that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @JamesRonald $\vec r =(x,y,z)$ is the position vector form the origin and $ |vec r|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is its lenght.

Comment: @JamesRonald We indicete usually $r:=|\vec r|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.